# API Access to setting up Endurance Storage/iSCSI snapshots and schedules?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, iscsi

Is there a way through either the IBM Cloud API, or the Softlayer API, to programmatically run/schedule/setup snapshots on an endurance storage device?  aka iSCSI drive.

I've looked through the documentation, but have not found anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to take a look at these methods:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/softlayer_network_storage/createsnapshot

the method above will allow you to create a new manual snapshot

https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/softlayer_network_storage/enablesnapshots

the method above will allow you to schedule the snapshots

see bellow some examples of code:

https://softlayer.github.io/php/enableSnapshots/

https://softlayer.github.io/rest/createsnapshot/